# Minimum Order Quantity by Cart

Tags: checkout, customer

We had a website that was built with a minimum checkout quantity. It currently does not allow you to checkout without ordering 16 units. We now want get rid of this rule, and go to a standard $ qty which is easy to find in admin......

Any ideas where we may find this setup and cancel it (the 16 unit minimum that is).

Regards

Comment: Which version of magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**For Magento 1.x:**

- Login to admin panel and go to `System > Configuration > Catalog (Iventory)`.
- Under **Product Stock Options**, there will be option for **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart**. Change value of it to required value or delete all rules in this option if you don't want it.

**For Magento 2.x:**

- Login to admin panel and go to `Stores > Configuration > Catalog (Iventory)`.
- Under **Product Stock Options**, there will be option for **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart**. Change value of it to required value or delete all rules in this option if you don't want it.

Please let me know if you find any problem.